# Performance of checking if value differs from value in another list

Tags: c#

This is more a question in regard to best performance way to handle this.  I have two lists that have a invoice number and balance.  I need to get the value from my first list that the invoice number equals the invoice number from the 2nd list and the balance is different. Is Linq except the best way to handle this delta or is there a better way.  Example lists:

```
var collection1 = new List<InvoiceBalances>();
var collection2 = new List<InvoiceReconcile>();
```

Looking for all value in the 1st collection1 InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber and Balance not equal.

Comment: If the lists are guaranteed to contain the same invoices, and in the same order you can just compare `collection1` with `collection2`, item by item, by index. If they're not ordered the same, you can order them, but if they're not guaranteed to contain the same invoices you're best served by converting one of them to a lookup, as in `var lookup2 = collection2.ToLookup(c => c.InvoiceNumber);`, and then looping on the other. A lookup is like a dictionary, except it can have multiple values and will produce an empty collection for a key, if the key is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ you can do this :

```
var res = collection1.Where(x => collection2.Any(y => y.InvoiceNumber == x.InvoiceNumber && y.Balance != x.Balance));
```

This query will fetch all the entries in `collection1` which has corresponding entry in `collection2` such that their `InvoiceNumber` is same but `Balance` is different.

Comment: ain't this solution a little performance hungry...its complexity would `O(n * m)`, considering `collection1` has `n` elems and `collection2` has `m` elems...

Comment: _and the balance is different._

Comment: @reyad Considering that op is working on lists, there might be no simple way to achieve this. Hashmap/Hashset may be a good solution to improve performance. Not sure how likely op is to change his implementation for performance.

Comment: I only need to check though if the Balance is different because other properties could differ.

Comment: @Jasmeet But OP said, `This is more a question in regard to best performance way to handle this.` I guess, (s)he meant to have best performance solution. So, using a `Map` may help a little bit...rather than just `List`. But, of course, its a matter of choice of OP.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the difference in Balance.

Comment: @reyad  Oh yes, I think you are right, the code needs to be updated to use hash maps to improve performance than this.